# Using javaScript how to read parameter based routing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm referring to this code:

```
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5"; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
console.log(c);
```

I'm getting **c** value but when I change url to

```
http://172.16.1.135:458/EMS/Index.html#/Login?c=John&securityToken=3D5813AB-6E83-43D9-8B1F-277548D874D1|13|1548340074273
```

I'm not getting value of **c**

Comment: It's unclear. What are you trying to do again? Explain "not working" (not very useful)

Comment: @JeremyThille i wana to store my userName and security Token in my localStorage

Comment: Use `$stateParams.userName` and `$stateParams.securityToken`. If Url is route.

Comment: @JOHNMickh Well, it's easy : `localStorage.setItem("userName", userName)` and then, `localStorage.getItem("userName")`

Comment: @JeremyThille Here what is userName Like how can i get userName

Comment: I don't know, you know it. You asked, `i wana to store my userName in my localStorage`, I told you exactly how to do that. The problem is that your question is still very unclear, we don't understand what you're trying to do. You ask, how can I store my userName in my localStorage, when actually you don't even have this userName. So it's not the right question, and we're completely lost. Please edit your original question and make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use any route module for it, use the `$location` service:

```
console.log($location.search());
```

Of course remember to inject the `$location` service

Comment: im getting object{}

Comment: there should be your query params there too, so try `$location.search().userName`

Comment: its giving me undefind